# Categorise by week number of each year in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, expression, arcade

I am new to ArcGIS Pro, and I would like to have a categorised symbology based on the year and week number of the year in question.
For ex:

- 2022: Week 1
- 2022: Week 2
- 2022: Week 3
- ...
- 2023: Week 1
- ...

My date format is "MM/dd/yyyy"
I tried the following in the expression Builder but it returns 2 values: "NA" and "Year NaN - Week NaN

```
if (IsEmpty(receiptDat) || receiptDat == "NA") {
  return "NA";
}
else {
  var dateObj = Date(receiptDat, "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var year = Year(dateObj);
  var isoWeek = ISOWeek(dateObj);
  return "Year " + year + " - Week " + isoWeek;
}
```

I also tried

`Concatenate(Year($feature.receiptDat), ': ', 'Week', ISOweek($feature.receiptDat))`

But it doesn't work... I would be very gratefull for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question:

```
if (IsEmpty($feature.receiptDat) || $feature.receiptDat == "NA") {
  return "NA";
}
else {
  var date_array = split($feature.receiptDat, "/") // Split text value into an array
  var m = date_array[0] - 1; // Month 0 is January
  var d = date_array[1];
  var y = date_array[2];
  var dateObj = Date(y, m, d);
  var isoWeek = ISOWeek(dateObj);
 return "Year " + y + " : Week " + text(isoWeek, '00'); // isoWeek transformed to text in '00' format to ensure proper chronological order
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be reading the help file and understand what it is telling you. If you look at the [Date()](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/date_functions/#date) function it clearly states it has 3 signatures.  You state in your question you are providing it a string in the format of "MM/dd/yyyy". Now read the help file, are any of the signatures it says it can do the same as what you are supplying it? No, you are just making things up, none of the signatures take a field and a string.  That's why you are getting NaN as you are inputting into the Date function nonsensical values.